# What's the connection

Tags: connections-puzzle

This is the very first puzzle in the Only Connect puzzle book.

> What’s the connection?

> Reunion of broken parts

> Pebble

> Measurement of the Earth

> Triangle measurement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> They are branches of mathematics.

> Algebra - Reunion of broken parts is the literal Arabic translation

> Calculus - Pebble is the literal Latin translation

> Geometry - Measurement of the earth is the literal Greek translation

> Trigonometry - Triangle measurement is the literal Greek translation

Comment: rot13(Trbzrgel vf Terrx sbe zrnfherzrag bs gur rnegu (ab crooyr). Pnyphyhf vf Yngva sbe crooyr. Gurer'f ab rnegu va gevt.)

Comment: @cap Thanks. I think I got confused by the original layout of the puzzle. Should have seen it though.

Comment: No idea why you got a downvote. It's a good answer.